# php - how to convert unicode to utf-8 string

Tags: php, string, unicode, utf-8, meta-tags

I've a string like this :

```
%d8%b7%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%ad%db%8c-%d8%a7%d9%be%d9%84%db%8c%da%a9%db%8c%d8%b4%d9%86-%d9%81%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%b4%da%af%d8%a7%d9%87%db%8c
```

the meta tag of page is set to utf-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

i want to convert this unicode to pure readable utf-8 string

I've tested lots of code ,thie is my last code :

```
 function convertFarsi($str) {
        return html_entity_decode(preg_replace('/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/i', '&#x$1;', $str),ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
```

and it doesn't work.
How can I convert these unicode to utf8 string ?

Comment: What would you like the end result to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [url_decode](https://www.php.net/function.urldecode) to get the following result:

```
    <?php
    
    $string = '%d8%b7%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%ad%db%8c-%d8%a7%d9%be%d9%84%db%8c%da%a9%db%8c%d8%b4%d9%86-%d9%81%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%b4%da%af%d8%a7%d9%87%db%8c';
    
    $outpout = urldecode($string);
    
    echo $outpout; // طراحی-اپلیکیشن-فروشگاهی
```

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't decode unicode characters. I wrote a function that does.

```
function unicode_urldecode($url)
{
    preg_match_all('/%u([[:alnum:]]{4})/', $url, $a);
   
    foreach ($a[1] as $uniord)
    {
        $dec = hexdec($uniord);
        $utf = '';
       
        if ($dec < 128)
        {
            $utf = chr($dec);
        }
        else if ($dec < 2048)
        {
            $utf = chr(192 + (($dec - ($dec % 64)) / 64));
            $utf .= chr(128 + ($dec % 64));
        }
        else
        {
            $utf = chr(224 + (($dec - ($dec % 4096)) / 4096));
            $utf .= chr(128 + ((($dec % 4096) - ($dec % 64)) / 64));
            $utf .= chr(128 + ($dec % 64));
        }
       
        $url = str_replace('%u'.$uniord, $utf, $url);
    }
   
    return urldecode($url);
}
```

[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)
[Demo](https://linahouse.vn/tui-xach-vi-thoi-trang-c4.html)

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do it:

```
<?php
$s = '%d8%b7%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%ad%db%8c-%d8%a7%d9%be%d9%84%db%8c%da%a9%db%8c%d8%b4%d9%86-%d9%81%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%b4%da%af%d8%a7%d9%87%db%8c';
$t = urldecode($s);
var_dump($t == 'طراحی-اپلیکیشن-فروشگاهی');
```

https://php.net/function.urldecode